# Google Recaptcha V2 problems with SSL

Tags: php, recaptcha

My code to run google recaptcha v2 is not working with SSL. Same code works for other servers without ssl. With this SSL server I have the response of fail: Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.

This is for a PHP server. I tested the same scrip in other servers and it works fine.

```
<?php
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'mysecretkeyhere',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

        // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
        $senderEmail = $_POST["email"];
        $recipient= "myemailhere";
        $subject = "New Customer From website";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "<h1>New Message From  Website</h1>"."\r\n".
    '<p>Customer Email: ' .'<b>'.$senderEmail .'</b>'.'</p>'
            .'<p>Customer Name: ' .'<b>' .$_POST["name"] .'</b>'.'</p>' 
            .'<p>Customer Phone Number: ' .'<b>'.$_POST["telephone"] .'</b>' .'</p>' .'<p>Customer Message: </p>';
        $body = '<p>' .$_POST["Message"] .'</p>';
        mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers,'-f ' .$senderEmail);

        header('Location: ../thankyou.html');

    }
?>
```

After I click the submit button I have the error: Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.

Comment: Any way you could dump the `$res` variable when there's a failure so that you can actually see what Google might be complaining about?  Most often, it's the referrer restriction, which may be set to http but not https.

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't know how to do that, I am new at programming. Thank you for response. This script used to work and now is not working because the https of the website.

Comment: There's a configuration in your captcha control panel that says which websites to expect a request from.  If you put http and not https, then that would explain the difference.  if you `var_dump($res)` where your "echo" is today, you might see the description that the Google service has, which will help you understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: Paul, I did go to the control panel for the domains that captcha will allow and the Google control panel does not let me add the https:// at the beginning of the domain.
Also, I did what you mention and it says NULL on the webpage after submitting the form.

Comment: Your best bet is to dump the `$res` variable to see what the error is.

Comment: yes I did that and when I submit the form it says NULL I don't know why because the same method worked for other webpages. The only difference on this one is the ssl

Comment: You get NULL if what you feed to json_decode is not valid JSON to begin with. You should first of all check what `$result` actually contains.

Comment: misorude, thanks, I checked and it says NULL as well. This whole code works in other servers, this server is a IIS server with PHP as well and SSL, that would be the difference with the other servers where this code works fine. I don't understand would it be the SSL of the page that is affecting or the IIS but it has php, other php scripts work. Thanks...

Comment: I entered the google recaptcha console and i found this message: "We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. "